# At what point during a typical request does the $wpdb object become available?

Tags: php, actions, wpdb

I've wrote some custom SQL queries inside a class method and noticed they seem to work if I hook the method to the `wp` action. If I hook to the `plugins_loaded` action, they don't seem to work.

**My question:**

At what point during a typical request does the `$wpdb` object become available?

Refs:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, post your code because the problem is not the one you guessed.

Actually, `$wpdb` is available very early: it is inited by the function [`require_wp_db()`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/require_wp_db/) located in the file [`wp_settings.php` at line #79](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L79).

The hook `'plugins_loaded'` is fired in the same `wp_settings.php` file, but at line [#237](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L237), so pretty after `$wpdb` is available.